# permission do django

Tags: html, django, template, permissões, model

Boa tarde, eu estou querendo no template fazer um laço para desabilitar um botão de acordo com a permissão customizada ..
O código do model esta:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class PermUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tecnico = models.ForeignKey('imuno.Tecnico')

    def __str__(self):
        return ''

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
                       ("SIR", "Somente Imprimir Relatorio"),
                      )
```

No template eu faço:

```
{% if show_save %}
       {% if perm.permissao.SIR %}
            <button type="submit" title="{% trans 'Save' %}" class="list-group-item disabled" name="_save">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>
              <span class="text">{% trans 'Save' %}</span>
            </button>
       {% else %}
            <button type="submit" title="{% trans 'Save' %}" class="list-group-item active" name="_save">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>
              <span class="text">{% trans 'Save' %}</span>
            </button>
       {% endif %}
 {% endif %}
```

Estando ou não com a permissão ele mostra o botão caso eu ponha "not" com ou sem permissão fica desabilitado. Alguém saberia qual o erro? na documentação do django mostra essa forma de aplicar a chamada da perm no template.

Comment: O que tem dentro da variável `perm`? Você tentou debugar imprimindo `{{ perm.permissao.SIR }}` e vendo se o que você esperava está chegando por essa variável?

Comment: A variável que armazena as permissões é a "perms" (https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/1.10/topics/auth/default/#permissions)

Comment: Então realmente é perms, tá retornando True sempre mesmo estando ou não com a permissão. como se ao retirar ela não atualizasse.